# Pointer question

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class example:

```
class local
{ 
  public:
    int var;
};


local * plocal = (local *)0x74673;
local * plocal2 = *(local **)0x74673;
```

I know it means nothing it's just an example...

I just want to understand the diff between `plocal` and `plocal2`

Comment: The first one compiles , while the second one doesn't? You can't convert a local** to a local*.

Comment: @Ernest: `*(local **)` looks fine. :) The part there-after, doesn't.

Comment: @ernest: .... you dont have right

Comment: He edited the code after I commented. I agree, it's fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plocal2` is a pointer to *local structure*, who pointer was taken from address `0x74673`.

`plocal` is a pointer to *local structure*, who structure is allocated at memory address `0x74673`